# Use bash -s with other arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have install.sh script which is located in server. I want to write one line code to download and run the script.

```
curl -s https://my-server/install.sh | bash
```

Everything works fine until I am trying to set arguments

```
curl -s https://my-server/install.sh | bash -s -p abc
```

It can't recognize '-p' as an argument but 'abc' can.

How to set arguments in this situation starting with '-' or '--' signs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start your argument list after `--` separator:

```
curl -s https://my-server/install.sh | bash -s -- -p abc
```

As per `man bash`:

> A `--` signals the end of options and disables further option processing.   Any  arguments  after  the  `--`  are
>                    treated as filenames and arguments.  An argument of `-` is equivalent to `--`.